# trying to pass the name of a function in a variable for if(typeof ...)

Tags: javascript, function, typeof

Basically i am trying to check if a function exist dynamically..

This is my code:

```
var somevar = 'somefunction';

if(typeof somevar === 'function'){
    somefunction();
}

function somefunction(){
   alert('something');
}
```

The above code doesn't work

Is there a way to achieve what i am trying to accomplish ?

Comment: Yea i know its a string... but bellow it its also defined as function you're missing the point..

Comment: Why don't you check against a reference to the function instead of a string?

Comment: I mean, `var somevar = somefunction;`.

Comment: What do you mean against the reference to the function bfavaretto

Comment: I mean, do you really need the function name in a string? Because if you use `var somevar = somefunction` (note, no quotes), your `typeof` line works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
var somevar = 'somefunction';

if(typeof eval(somevar) === 'function'){
    //somefunction();
    eval(somevar+'()');
}

function somefunction(){
   alert('something');
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much that is exactly what i were looking for

Answer (score 0):

If the function is *global*, you can check via;

```
if (typeof window[somevar] === "function") {

}
```

Otherwise, you're just checking the type of the variable "somevar" (which, in this case, in a string).

If it isn't global, but exists on some object, you can replace `window` in the above example with the name of the object the potential function exists on. If it's just a function by itself in a non-global scope, you're out of luck.

Comment: No, that's not the problem. The problem is whether the function is in the *global* scope or not?

Comment: Yes the function is global but how is that to do with the variable ?

Comment: @NetaMeta: Haha, sorry, now I understand the confusion. My brain was thinking one thing, and my keyboard was typing another. Does my answer make more sense now?

Comment: yea the second one was correct however the window[] kinda limits me in some way and i rather use the eval() instead as its more what i am after.  Thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

some kind of
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p3a4A/)

```
var somevar = 'somefunction';

if(isFunction(eval(somevar))){
    eval(somevar+'()');
}

function somefunction(){
   alert('something');
}

function isFunction(x){
    return Object.prototype.toString.call(x) === "[object Function]";
}
```