# What is inside of my existing function? Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, typeof

Please don't downvote my question, I've spent 20 minutes searching for an answer. This is the best ive found, and can't get it to work. This is in Javascript.

[trying to pass the name of a function in a variable for if(typeof ...)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16753970/trying-to-pass-the-name-of-a-function-in-a-variable-for-iftypeof)

I'm trying to complete a project made by someone else, and I think they created a function.

```
 Chat.fetch()
```

I can not get it to work, or figure out how to use it. My question is very specific. How do I figure out what is inside of Chat.fetch()    ??

example: If Chat.fetch()   is a loop that counts to 10, I want to do something so I can see exactly what that "formula" looks like.

I tried looking at the "typeof" but don't know how to work it. any suggestions?

Comment: You need to tell us what you mean by "I can not get it to work?" Are you sure that function exists? We need many more details.

Comment: In the instructions, it says "experiment with Chat.fetch()   so I'm pretty sure it is a working function of some sort. When I say I can not get it to work, I will get a return saying "undefined" followed by  an error that says "undefined is not a function".

Comment: This means that `Chat` is undefined. Either you're not loading the JavaScript that defines `Chat` or you've got the name wrong. You should explore your code with the developer tools to get oriented. There's simply not enough details for us to help you substantially at this time.

Comment: Actually, you have helped me tremendously. I don't know if you remember what it was like being a beginner. or maybe it's just me, but.. I am not experienced enough to ask an educated question. so I really appreciate the support.

Comment: I'm with the OP. This question seems clear. He wants a method to find out what code exists in the function chat.fetch(). Why was this closed?

Answer (score 2):

```
console.log(chat.fetch);
```

I found this out by mistake. If forget the parentheses expected after fetch, the console write out fetch's definition instead of the result of the function.

Hope this works for you.

Comment: chat.fetch.toString() will also work

Comment: I don't know if the full function body appears in all browsers, but it definitely appears in Chrome. If console.log doesn't do it, try just entering "chat.fetch" on its own.

Comment: I tried doing Chat.fetch on it's own and this is what I got.    
    Chat.fetch
    function () { [provided code] }

Comment: Jacob, Reinmar, skuntsel, soon, soner Gonul,  I don't understand why you can't tell what is being asked. If you read the question it says: My question is very specific. How do I figure out what is inside of Chat.fetch() ??   How is that a vague question? I'm not trying to be rude, I am trying to understand why that is difficult to understand

Answer (score 2):

Most web browsers have developer tools, which you typically can open by hitting <kbd>F12</kbd>. From there, you should be able to look at all of the JavaScript loaded in your page, read the source code, and even set breakpoints.